# Disable logging for a specific celery task

Tags: python, celery

I have implemented logging for my celery app using the Python `logging` library. One current issue I am facing is that I have a lot of noise in my logs due to a `beat` that is running every second or so. In the grand scheme of things, I still want to have log messages mentioning that "Task A was received" and "Task A was successful", but I was looking for a way within the celery config to turn logs for this specific `beat` task to a `debug` mode, for example, or turn them off in general. Is this supported in the `celery` framework.

Comment: Disable the specific logger which is logging those beats. Do you have the logger name?

Comment: @stoneman_41, did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @Chognificent I did not, unfortunately